# Upgrade openssl on Linode server but how to decide 'ENGINESDIR'

Tags: linux, openssl

On Linode Server, it has already installed openssl, but version is `1.1.0`. But I want to try some features like TLSv1_3, so I decide to upgrade it to latest version.

My old openssl version like this:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: debian-amd64
compiler: gcc -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/lib/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1\"" 
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
```

Due to it is "upgrade", so I try to retain as original as possible. Through some website I made this `./config` command.

```
./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/lib/ssl threads shared zlib-dynamic no-ssl no-tls1 no-tls1_1 -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DENGINESDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1
```

It's long, but important is last phrase: `-DENGINESDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1`

And problem happended when I used `make` command. Here are the **error** message:

```
<command-line>:0:0: warning: "ENGINESDIR" redefined
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
crypto/cversion.c: In function 'OpenSSL_version':
<command-line>:0:13: error: 'usr' undeclared (first use in this function)
crypto/cversion.c:38:33: note: in expansion of macro 'ENGINESDIR'
     return "ENGINESDIR: \"" ENGINESDIR "\"";
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
<command-line>:0:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
crypto/cversion.c:38:33: note: in expansion of macro 'ENGINESDIR'
     return "ENGINESDIR: \"" ENGINESDIR "\"";
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
<command-line>:0:17: error: 'lib' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'ldiv'?
crypto/cversion.c:38:33: note: in expansion of macro 'ENGINESDIR'
     return "ENGINESDIR: \"" ENGINESDIR "\"";
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
<command-line>:0:21: error: 'x86_64' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean '__x86_64'?
crypto/cversion.c:38:33: note: in expansion of macro 'ENGINESDIR'
     return "ENGINESDIR: \"" ENGINESDIR "\"";
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
<command-line>:0:34: error: 'gnu' undeclared (first use in this function)
crypto/cversion.c:38:33: note: in expansion of macro 'ENGINESDIR'
     return "ENGINESDIR: \"" ENGINESDIR "\"";
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
<command-line>:0:38: error: 'engines' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'engine_st'?
crypto/cversion.c:38:33: note: in expansion of macro 'ENGINESDIR'
     return "ENGINESDIR: \"" ENGINESDIR "\"";
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
crypto/cversion.c:38:44: error: expected ';' before string constant
     return "ENGINESDIR: \"" ENGINESDIR "\"";
                                        ^~~~
```

It seems split my directory into different pars...

That's it, my question is should I set `ENGINESDIR` manully? If i discard `-DENGINESDIR` param could `ENGINES` also point to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1`? Or there are any better choise? I am not familiar with openssl, I can only write command like that from lots of google.

PS1:My new openssl version is `1.1.1-pre9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `openssl version -a` mentions in the line that starts with `copmpiler:`

```
-DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1\""
```

This is the same as you had, but with double double quotes around it, the inner ones escaped.

In order to achieve that inside your `config` script, you will have to escape the double quotes and backslashes, since those will be expanded as soon as you invoke the script. This should do the trick when invoking `config`:

```
-DENGINESDIR=\"\\\"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1\\\"\"
```

---

**Update**

After the OP's remarks in his own answer, I spent a bit more time looking at this issue by trying different things myself. The approach proposed above does remove the compilation error and allows the build to complete. However, it is not the correct solution.

To dig more into this, I used the following command to set up the `Makefile`.

```
$ ./config --prefix=/tmp/openssl -DENGINESDIR=\"\\\"/tmp/openssl-engines\\\"\"
```

The resulting output when doing `make install` after that contained many lines like these:

```
gcc  -I. -Icrypto/include -Iinclude -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG
    -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC
    -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5
    -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM
    -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
    -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM
    -DENGINESDIR="\"/tmp/openssl-engines\"" -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/tmp/openssl/ssl\""
    -DENGINESDIR="\"/tmp/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -Wall -O3 -pthread -m64
    -DL_ENDIAN  -Wa,--noexecstack -fPIC -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE
    -MMD -MF crypto/bn/bn_div.d.tmp -MT crypto/bn/bn_div.o -c
    -o crypto/bn/bn_div.o crypto/bn/bn_div.c
<command-line>:0:0: warning: "ENGINESDIR" redefined
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definiti
```

Note that `-DENGINESDIR` appears twice, hence the warning emitted. The last one overrides the first one so this does not result in the desired outcome.

Further investigation shows, like the OP indicated in his answer as well, the `Makefile` has a "hardcoded" line `ENGINESDIR=$(libdir)/engines-1.1` that can not be overridden and is preventing customization of this aspect. It is therefore useless to use the `-DENGINES` value with `Configure`.

Without going into too much detail: to make the `ENGINESDIR` value configurable, the file `Configurations/unix-Makefile.tmpl` has to be modified to contain the following lines, similar to those for the `openssldir` setting:

```
ENGINESDIR={- use File::Spec::Functions;
              our $enginesdir =
                  $config{enginesdir} ?
                      (file_name_is_absolute($config{enginesdir}) ?
                           $config{enginesdir}
                           : catdir($prefix, $config{enginesdir}))
                      : catdir($prefix, "engines");
              $enginesdir -}
```

and a handful of lines need to be added to the `Configure` file to introduce the actual `--enginesdir` parameter.

After doing that, the following sequence of commands did work as expected:

```
$ ./config --prefix=/tmp/openssl --enginesdir=/tmp/openssl-engines
$ make && make install && make install_engines
```

This is all way beyond what the OP was asking for and I threw a few hours into the black hole called OpenSSL, but it was educational anyway.

Comment: Did the compiler error that you posted not go away when you added the quotes? (By the way, it seems like the recommended way is to surround that expression with another extra pair of double quotes, although I do not see that would make a difference. I updated the answer with that.)

Comment: I miss press `Enter` button then send my incomplete message and I can't immediately edit my comments, damn Stackoverflow...Here are complete one:

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but It can't pass through either.  I tried to replace end part of command with escaped double quotes and that error show again and looks same. I found a file named `Makefile`, and there is a `CONFIGURE_ARGS` propertie in that file.  In the last phrase of this propertie there are lots of settings  like : `CONFIGURE_ARGS=("...lots of my other -D conf", "-DENGINESDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1")`. Actually It's the same with when I use no escaped double quotes. So maybe this made problem same again.

Comment: Double quotes same, heartbroken result. 

Comment: I updated again, I did not realize that the extra `config` step is a part of the problem. Can you try the new expression as well please?

Comment: I found a way maybe could solve my problem, but also adopt your advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Through a little time search in a metioned file, I found the answer finally.
When you eager to solve a problem but totally no any sense of that, but if you unintentionl pass several days and come back random to think and search again you will find the answer how it close to be.. LIFE IS STRANGE.
The key file is `Makefile`, which is in your like `.../openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1-pre9/` dir where you try to use `make` command, there are some paragraphs jump into my eyes suddenly and attract me immediately:

```
# Do not edit these manually. Use Configure with --prefix or --openssldir
# to change this!  Short explanation in the top comment in Configure
INSTALLTOP=/usr
OPENSSLDIR=/usr/lib/ssl
LIBDIR=lib
# $(libdir) is chosen to be compatible with the GNU coding standards
libdir=$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)
ENGINESDIR=$(libdir)/engines-1.1
```

Looks at compose style of `ENGINESDIR` and associate with my commands, soon I realized the key of relationship between these dir.

so I modified my command, delete original `-DENGINESDIR` and add something make command looks like:

`./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/lib/ssl --libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ...`

and `make` again, miracle happended, passed and no any errors, even warnnings. And I try `make test`, it passed too, only skip some thing but it's normal.

Although I don't try `make install` to verify whether `ENGINES` point to my old dir. But I think it should be ok.

SO the key is not to set the `ENGINES` dir manually, because it is composed by two dir named `INSTALLTOP`, `LIBDIR`. In the `INSTALL.md` file (the file lie in the openssl github repo ) only metioned user could use `--prefix` to change the prefix, but in these file I found there are others not metioned but style same param could change `LIBDIR` where `ENGINESDIR` rely on it. Maybe it acutally uses infrequently so markdown file didn't mention all the possiable params.

And very thanks to [Reinier Torenbeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380680/reinier-torenbeek), without him I won't reconsider this answer again. Maybe that is not a hard problem, but I actually can't slove it before the answer I met. And I adopt his advice as the answer.

Comment: Since you accepted my answer (thanks), I wanted to make sure I deserved it :-) See the update in my answer which analyses the problem further (if you are still not fed up with it by now...)